# Leaflet heatmap overlay breaks moving to Angular 6 with Dot Net Core 2.1

Tags: angular, webpack, leaflet, angular-cli, heatmap

I am currently moving my angular code from the old Dot Net Core Angular template to the new angular-cli version. I completely replaced the angular 5 cli that was in the Angular template with the new Angular 6 version, and got the basic site all up and running successfully.

Next I started moving some of my components across. One of those components is a leaflet mapping component that shows a map of my country with regional overlays. That is working beautifully. However, I have a heatmap component (heatmap.js) that was working in the old angular template that I can't quite figure out how to get working in the new angular template.

In the old template, I added heatmap.js and leaflet-heatmap to my package.json file:

```
"leaflet": "1.3.1",
"heatmap.js": "2.0.5",
"leaflet-heatmap": "1.0.0",
```

then, because heatmap doesn't conform to the correct structure for importing into Angular from an npm package, I added the following to the webpack.config.vendor.js file:

```
"heatmap.js/build/heatmap.min.js",
"leaflet-heatmap/leaflet-heatmap.js",
```

In my code, I was then able to import heatmap and leaflet-heatmap, and declare the HeatmapOverlay variable.

```
import "heatmap.js";
import "leaflet-heatmap";
declare var HeatmapOverlay: any;
```

And the heatmap would work:
[image: Heatmap overlay]

Now that I am on angular-cli, it is a bit different because webpack itself is not exposed, and it looks like it shouldn't need to be. I should be able to run exactly the same code if I set up the import correctly. So I added the same packages to the package.json file:

```
"leaflet": "1.3.1",
"heatmap.js": "2.0.5",
"leaflet-heatmap": "1.0.0",
```

and this time, I thought to handle the import of the incorrectly structured scripts, I could add it to the angular.json file, as follows:

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/heatmap.js/build/heatmap.min.js",
              "node_modules/leaflet-heatmap/leaflet-heatmap.js"
            ],
```

Unfortunately, this fails, with the following error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: HeatmapOverlay is not defined

I think it's really a question about how to get the old webpack.config.vendor.js structure converted to the new angular.json format. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: I am trying to implement the same thing. Can you please help me with the code?

Answer (score 0):

It's alright, I have figured it out. I just had to add the prerequisite leaflet script into the list of scripts in angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
              "node_modules/heatmap.js/build/heatmap.min.js",
              "node_modules/leaflet-heatmap/leaflet-heatmap.js"
            ]
```